NDSolve does not take into account the boundary condition
I am using the following script to solve a coupled pde.
I get the error "NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the 
differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from 
those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial 
conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is 
recommended."
I have no idea where the error comes from as The initial condition satisfies the boundary condition. In addition, the outcome does not satisfy the boundary conditions
eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - u0  Exp[- t ];

and
eq2[[-1]] = vU[[-1]] - ul  Exp[- t ];

. Could anyone please help me with solving this issue?
sol[b_, m_] := Module[{tmax = 6, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy];
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU;
   mu = RealAbs[u1]^(m - 1);
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t])  xgrid  a1 + 1/L[t]  M1 . (vA  vU);
   (**)
   u0 = 0.5;
   ul = 2;
   cl = (u0 - ul) L[0]^(b/m - 1);
   eq1[[1]] = D[vA[[1]], t];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA  mu  u1);
   eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - u0  Exp[- t ];
   eq2[[-1]] = vU[[-1]] - ul  Exp[- t ];
   eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, 
     vU - (ul + cl (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^(-b/m + 1)) /. 
      t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}];
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3];
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]; s[[1]]];

sol11 = sol[1, 1.5];
lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 6, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0,
    6, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];
x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol11; xmax = x0[1];
{DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], a[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 6}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "a", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], u[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 6}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "u", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 6}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "L"}]}
Animate[Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t], t]], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 3}}], {t, 0, 6}]
Animate[Plot[u[x/x0[t], t], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 4}}], {t, 0, 6}]

